# Calculate powers of 2 from user input

Tags: python

I'm totally new to programming. Picked up a PDF and I'm trying out Exercises given. But now I'm stuck with the following task:

> Write a Python program that allows the user to enter any integer
>   value, and displays the value of 2 raised to that power. Your program
>   should function as shown below
>
> ```
> What power of two? __
> Two to power of __ is __
> ```

I think it should start something like this:

```
x=input("What power of two? ")
```

but what's next? or is it right at all?

Comment: answer should be in two lines btw

Comment: Use pow function. `Pow(2,x)`

Comment: pow(2,x) gives the same error as with **

Comment: Which error is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get an error with pow(2, x) it's probably because of typing, you should convert the string from `input` to a number, like `int` or `float`

```
>>> e = float(input('What power of two?'))
What power of two?1.2
>>> pow(2, e)
2.2973967099940698
```

Comment: The output can be as `print "Two to power of"+str(e)+" is "+str(pow(2,e))`

Comment: @BhargavRao: Yuck. Use the [`str.format()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) instead.

Comment: @TimPietzcker The OP is just a beginner, we ought to think at his level.

Comment: @BhargavRao: Good point. `print "Two to power of", e, "is", pow(2,e)` would be much nicer, though.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Yeah. It is better. Sorry, had forgotten that "comma" strategy in Python

Comment: this one was really helpful guys, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple, really.
Python has this operator for Powers: **

*e.g.* `print(2**10)` will print 1024.

One more thing- you'll have to type `x = int(input("*Whatever you want to enter*"))`, as input() returns a String.